# Need help to identify this PCB connector

Tags: identification, connector, flexible

I really need to identify the name of this connector type.
It is the PCB end of a lightning connector on a FLIR thermal camera for IOS.

[image: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/story-of-a-flir-one-lightning-connector/?action=dlattach;attach=721797;image]

[image]

Mine is just like this but with lightning instead of this USB-C
[image]

Comment: Looks like a pretty ordinary mezzanine connector to me. I've seen tons like it on digikey.

Comment: there's a logo on the connector

Comment: You are basically looking at mezzanine, 2 signal 2 power connector. It's keyed and it's not on digikey. Maybe the product has reach EOL and was replaced by something else. This look quite similar: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/hirose-electric-co-ltd/BM29B-2DP-2-0-35V-53/6036327 If this matches pin spacing you could replace both connector and socket.

Comment: Thanks guys, good tips, I looked at some better photos that I had and it looks like `HRS` logo, but I was not familiar with that name until now. I should be able to find the exact one, still looking a bit, but I am very close :) Or I might replace both ends as Damien says.